# How do I add a duplicate item to a list

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

With my wpf application, I am adding an item thats bound to a datagrid's selected value property to a list that is bound to a different datagrid, lets call it datagrid2. In datagrid2, there are a few columns that can be edited, but the issue is that when i add the same item to that list, what happens is that the duplicate items, when modified will have the same values. It's like it's referencing the same item, so when I try to create a new item to be added to that list, it still doesn't really do anything.

HOWEVER, it gets weird, because when I change to a different view (without resetting the viewmodel) and add the same item to the list bound to datagrid2, it acts normal again. Why?

EDIT:
I'm using MVVM btw..
Here's how I am adding an item to the list:

```
EstimateModel.EstimateItems.Add(SelectedItemRow);
```

Here's the datagrid xaml:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding EstimateModel.EstimateItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemRow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" AlternationCount="2" 
              SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False"
              RowHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource RowHeaderStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vendor Name" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path='Vendor'}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Name" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path='ItemName'}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style >
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="2*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path='Description'}" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style >
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Width=".5*" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding Path=NewQty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sell" Width=".5*" IsReadOnly="False" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=SellPrice, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=C, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="List" Width=".5*" IsReadOnly="True" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=ListPrice, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=C}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Finish" Width=".75*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path='ProductFinishCode'}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Category" Width=".75*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path='ProductCategory'}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cost" Width=".5*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path='CostPrice', StringFormat=C}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total" Width=".5*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path='LineTotal', StringFormat=C, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

EDIT 2:

```
var item = new ItemModel();
item = SelectedItemRow;
EstimateModel.EstimateItems.Add(item);
```

[Here is the problem that keeps happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6r6R.png) When I change the quantity for the first duplicate item, as you see, the other duplicate will automatically change to the same value.

Comment: yes, we need the code, otherwise we can't help

Comment: @Rodolfo added some code!

Comment: Whats is EstimateModel?, post your logic too, the C# code you are using to add the item. I think you already found the issue, remember that when you pass an object you really are passing the reference, and I think is this your case, thats why you see duplicated. But isn't clear for me, the code and a screenshot could help me to understand the whole scenario

Comment: EstimateModel is a name of a variable that is a "model" that holds a number of properties. I'll add a screenshot of what is happening, but my code to add the item is above the datagrid xaml. It's just a simple .Add. I figured its a reference thing, but how can I stop this from happening? (I will add some of my tested code and a screenshot)

Comment: @donwoncruton  What is the collection being used for the mentioned "list"? Some collection doesn't allow duplicated key. What is the class for EstimateModel.EstimateItems and EstimateModel?

Comment: EstimateModel.EstimateItems is a List<ItemModel>. EstimateModel is a custom type, the class for it is called "CreateEstimateModel" which holds a few properties. The ItemModel is also just a model for item properties. @Herbert